# Report services with multiple grouping

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I am new to reporting services. I have 2 tables:

- "cars" with columns id, cartype, capacity
- "values" with column id,carid, year, val1, val2

Records for these tables are:

```
Cars:
id    cartype  capacity

1     Passat   2200

2     BMW      2800

Values:
id    carid  year val1  val2

1      1     2012 100    1

2      1     2011 200    2

3      1     2010 300    3

4      2     2012 400    4

5      2     2011 500    5
```

I want to make a report that shows this:

```
Car Type    Capacity

Passat       2200


       2012   2011    2010

val1   100    200     300

val2    1      2      3


Car Type    Capacity

BMV       2800


       2012   2011 

val1   400    500   

val2   4      5
```

I made a data source with this select:

```
 SELECT m.Id AS carid, m.cartype, m.capacity, v.Id AS idval, v.An, v.val1, v.val2
 FROM  car AS m INNER JOIN  values AS v ON m.Id = v.carid
```

I have tried to use a matrix but I can't succeed in making this format.  Can somebody help me to obtain this report?

Comment: I Think You Want Repeat All Column of Metrix Right ? Ok Which Type Report You Should Use ?

Comment: I'm using sql server report.I want show once the combination car type -capacity and for each combination to show values(val1, val2) on years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **Dataset** is fine for this report.

You need to create a **List** based on the *Cars* Group, the within this **List** add two **Textboxes** for the *Car* details and a **Matrix** for *val1*, *val2*, etc.

A **List** allows you flexibility to place and move items as required, and placing a **Matrix** with the *Cars* group means it will only include values in scope for each *Car*. The **List** (and hence *Car* details and the values **Matrix**) will be repeated for each *Car* as required.

**Added after comment:**

It's impossible to say what was causing your error; it's really a specific implementation detail. To give an example of how this might be done I've mocked up a report. First step is to create the *Car* group:

[image]

You can see there is one **Group**, with one **Textbox**. In the **Textbox** there is a **Rectangle** (Lists in SSRS are just tables with Rectangles inserted). *Car* and *Capacity* are just **Textboxes**. In this example I've used two **Matrices**, but this could be done any number of ways. **Val1**:

[image]

**Val2**:

[image]

**Final result**:

[image]

So you can see it's very possible, you just need to understand the grouping required and how to construct a matrix. Unfortunately it's impossible to say what caused this error but hopefully this gives you something to aim towards.

Comment: After i done what you tell me , I receive an error : The tablix has a detail member with inner members.Detail members can only contain static inner members.

Comment: Added more details, please see above.